# how to solve The import com.atlassian cannot be resolved?

Tags: java, jsp, jira-plugin, openmeetings

Hello I am trying to develop my web application using jsp. I have 6 jsp pages in it. Pages are registration.jsp, login.jsp, r1.jsp, welcome.jsp, createroom.jsp and showroom.jsp respectivly. My goal is that when i login in login page, page should redirect in openmeeting server. For that i have created webservice like omRestService. For calling this Service i have created two java class omGateWay and OmPluginSettings respectivly. Everything works fine but error occurs in ompluginSetting class.error mention below.

```
import com.atlassian.sal.api.pluginsettings.PluginSettings;
import com.atlassian.sal.api.pluginsettings.PluginSettingsFactory;
 (The import com.atlassian cannot be resolved)
```

Here I am Providing you my OmPluginSeeting.java file  which has error. There are many errors occur at PluginSettingsFactory.

```
        package restService;

   import com.atlassian.sal.api.pluginsettings.PluginSettings;
   import com.atlassian.sal.api.pluginsettings.PluginSettingsFactory;
   import org.slf4j.Logger;
   import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

   public class OmPluginSettings
   {
 private static final Logger log = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(OmPluginSettings.class);
     final PluginSettingsFactory pluginSettingsFactory;

     public OmPluginSettings(PluginSettingsFactory pluginSettingsFactory)
     {
     this.pluginSettingsFactory = pluginSettingsFactory;
     }

     public void storeSomeInfo(String key, String value)
     {
   this.pluginSettingsFactory.createGlobalSettings().put("openmeetings:" + key, value);
     }

     public Object getSomeInfo(String key)
        {
    return this.pluginSettingsFactory.createGlobalSettings().get("openmeetings:" + key);
        }

     public void storeSomeInfo(String projectKey, String key, String value)
     {
     this.pluginSettingsFactory.createSettingsForKey(projectKey).put("openmeetings:" + key, 
     value);
     }

     public Object getSomeInfo(String projectKey, String key) {
    return this.pluginSettingsFactory.createSettingsForKey(projectKey).get("openmeetings:" 
     + key);
     }
   }
```

I also provide my restservice which is Given Below and totally error free.

```
    package restService;
            import java.io.BufferedReader;
            import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
            import java.io.IOException;
            import java.io.InputStream;
            import java.io.InputStreamReader;
            import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
            import java.net.MalformedURLException;
            import java.net.URI;
            import java.net.URL;
            import java.util.Iterator;
            import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
      import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
            import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
            import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpException;
            import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
            import org.dom4j.Document;
            import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
            import org.dom4j.Element;
            import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;
            import org.slf4j.Logger;
            import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

            public class omRestService
            {
            private static final Logger log = (Logger) 
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(omRestService.class);

              private URI getURI(String url) {
              return UriBuilder.fromUri(
                url).build(new Object[0]);
              }

              private String getEncodetURI(String url) throws MalformedURLException
              {
              return new URL(url).toString().replaceAll(" ", "%20");
              }

              public LinkedHashMap<String, Element> call(String request, Object param) 
              throws Exception
              {
              HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
              GetMethod method = null;
                try
                {
                method = new GetMethod(getEncodetURI(request).toString());
                }
                catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int statusCode = 0;
                try {
                statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
                }
                catch (HttpException e)
                {
                throw new Exception("Connection to OpenMeetings refused. Please check your  
                OpenMeetings configuration.");
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                throw new Exception("Connection to OpenMeetings refused. Please check your  
                 OpenMeetings configuration.");
                }

              switch (statusCode)
                {
                case 200:
                break;
                case 400:
                throw new Exception("Bad request. The parameters passed to the service did 
                not match 
                as expected. The Message should tell you what was missing or incorrect.");
                case 403:
               throw new Exception("Forbidden. You do not have permission to access this 
                resource, or 
                are over your rate limit.");
                case 503:
               throw new Exception("Service unavailable. An internal problem prevented us 
                   from 
                 returning data to you.");
                default:
               throw new Exception("Your call to OpenMeetings! Web Services returned an 
               unexpected  
                HTTP status of: " + statusCode);
                }

             InputStream rstream = null;
                try
                {
               rstream = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               throw new Exception("No Response Body");
                }

             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rstream));

             SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();

            Document document = null;
                String line;
                try
                {
                 // String line;
              while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                  {
                  //  String line;
                 document = reader.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(line.getBytes("UTF-8")));
                  }

                }
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                {
              e.printStackTrace();
              throw new Exception("UnsupportedEncodingException by SAXReader");
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               throw new Exception("IOException by SAXReader in REST Service");
                }
                catch (DocumentException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
               throw new Exception("DocumentException by SAXReader in REST Service");
                } finally {
              br.close();
                }

            Element root = document.getRootElement();

             LinkedHashMap elementMap = new LinkedHashMap();

            for (Iterator i = root.elementIterator(); i.hasNext(); )
                {
              Element item = (Element)i.next();

               if (item.getNamespacePrefix() == "soapenv") {
                throw new Exception(item.getData().toString());
                  }
               String nodeVal = item.getName();
              elementMap.put(nodeVal, item);
                }

             return elementMap;
              }
            }
```

After This RestService i have make OmGateWay class which has many method for integrate with openmeetings. which is given below:

```
          package org.openmeetings.jira.plugin.gateway;

          import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
          import org.dom    j.Element;
          import org.openmeetings.jira.plugin.ao.adminconfiguration.OmPluginSettings;
          import org.slf    j.Logger;
          import org.slf    j.LoggerFactory;

          public class OmGateway
          {
                  private static final Logger log =      
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(OmGateway.class);
            private OmRestService omRestService;
            private OmPluginSettings omPluginSettings;
            private String sessionId;

            public OmGateway(OmRestService omRestService, OmPluginSettings omPluginSettings)
            {
                    this.omRestService = omRestService;
                    this.omPluginSettings = omPluginSettings;
            }

            public Boolean loginUser() throws Exception
            {
                    LinkedHashMap result = null;

                    String url = (String)this.omPluginSettings.getSomeInfo("url");
                    String port = (String)this.omPluginSettings.getSomeInfo("port");
                    String userpass = (String)this.omPluginSettings.getSomeInfo("userpass");
                    String omusername = 
                    (String)this.omPluginSettings.getSomeInfo("username");

                    String sessionURL = "http://" + url + ":" + port + "/openmeetings
                     /services/      
                    UserService/getSession";

                    LinkedHashMap elementMap = this.omRestService.call(sessionURL, null);

                    Element item = (Element)elementMap.get("return");

                    setSessionId(item.elementText("session_id"));

                    log.info(item.elementText("session_id"));

                    result = this.omRestService.call("http://" + url + ":" + port + 
                    "/openmeetings/
                     services/UserService/loginUser?SID=" + getSessionId() + "&username=" + 
                     omusername 
                     + "&userpass=" + userpass, null);
                    if 

      (Integer.valueOf(((Element)result.get("return")).getStringValue()).intValue() >     
   )   {
                      return Boolean.valueOf(true);
              }
                    return Boolean.valueOf(false);
            }

            public Long addRoomWithModerationExternalTypeAndTopBarOption(Boolean 
            isAllowedRecording,   
            Boolean isAudioOnly, Boolean isModeratedRoom, String name, Long 
            numberOfParticipent, Long 
             roomType, String externalRoomType)
              throws Exception
            {
                    String url = (String)this.omPluginSettings.getSomeInfo("url");
                    String port = (String)this.omPluginSettings.getSomeInfo("port");

                    String roomId = "";

                    String restURL = "http://" + url + ":" + port + "/openmeetings/services/
                     RoomService/addRoomWithModerationExternalTypeAndTopBarOption?" + 
                      "SID=" + getSessionId() + 
                      "&name=" + name + 
                      "&roomtypes_id=" + roomType.toString() + 
                      "&comment=jira" + 
                      "&numberOfPartizipants=" + numberOfParticipent.toString() + 
                      "&ispublic=false" + 
                      "&appointment=false" + 
                      "&isDemoRoom=false" + 
                      "&demoTime=" + 
                      "&isModeratedRoom=" + isModeratedRoom.toString() + 
                      "&externalRoomType=" + externalRoomType + 
                      "&allowUserQuestions=" + 
                      "&isAudioOnly=" + isAudioOnly.toString() + 
                      "&waitForRecording=false" + 
                     "&allowRecording=" + isAllowedRecording.toString() + 
                     "&hideTopBar=false";

                   LinkedHashMap result = this.omRestService.call(restURL, null);

                   roomId = ((Element)result.get("return")).getStringValue();
                   return Long.valueOf(roomId);
            }

            public Long updateRoomWithModerationAndQuestions(Boolean isAllowedRecording, 
            Boolean 
             isAudioOnly, Boolean isModeratedRoom, String roomname, Long 
             numberOfParticipent, Long 
             roomType, Long roomId)
              throws Exception
            {
                   String url = (String)this.omPluginSettings.getSomeInfo("url");
                   String port = (String)this.omPluginSettings.getSomeInfo("port");
                   String updateRoomId = "";

                   String restURL = "http://" + url + ":" + port + "/openmeetings/services
                 /RoomService/
                   updateRoomWithModerationAndQuestions?" + 
                     "SID=" + getSessionId() + 
                     "&room_id=" + roomId.toString() + 
                     "&name=" + roomname.toString() + 
                     "&roomtypes_id=" + roomType.toString() + 
                     "&comment=" + 
                     "&numberOfPartizipants=" + numberOfParticipent.toString() + 
                     "&ispublic=false" + 
                     "&appointment=false" + 
                     "&isDemoRoom=false" + 
                     "&demoTime=" + 
                     "&isModeratedRoom=" + isModeratedRoom.toString() + 
                     "&allowUserQuestions=";

                   LinkedHashMap result = this.omRestService.call(restURL, null);

                   log.info("addRoomWithModerationExternalTypeAndTopBarOption with ID: ", 
                   ((Element)result.get("return")).getStringValue());

                   updateRoomId = ((Element)result.get("return")).getStringValue();

                   return Long.valueOf(updateRoomId);
            }

            public String setUserObjectAndGenerateRoomHash(String username, String 
            firstname, String 
            lastname, String profilePictureUrl, String email, String externalUserId, String 
              externalUserType, Long room_id, int becomeModeratorAsInt, int 
             showAudioVideoTestAsInt)
              throws Exception
            {
                   String url = (String)this.omPluginSettings.getSomeInfo("url");
                   String port = (String)this.omPluginSettings.getSomeInfo("port");
                   String roomHash = null;

                   String restURL = "http://" + url + ":" + port + "/openmeetings/services
               /UserService/
                    setUserObjectAndGenerateRoomHash?" + 
                     "SID=" + getSessionId() + 
                     "&username=" + username + 
                     "&firstname=" + firstname + 
                     "&lastname=" + lastname + 
                     "&profilePictureUrl=" + profilePictureUrl + 
                     "&email=" + email + 
                     "&externalUserId=" + externalUserId + 
                     "&externalUserType=" + externalUserType + 
                     "&room_id=" + room_id + 
                     "&becomeModeratorAsInt=" + becomeModeratorAsInt + 
                     "&showAudioVideoTestAsInt=" + showAudioVideoTestAsInt;

                   LinkedHashMap result = this.omRestService.call(restURL, null);

                   roomHash = ((Element)result.get("return")).getStringValue();

                   return roomHash;
            }

            public String getSessionId() {
                   return this.sessionId;
            }

            public void setSessionId(String sessionId) {
                   this.sessionId = sessionId;
            }
          }
```

I want to call loginuser method from OmGateway class on Jsp Button Click Event. Kindly help me to solve this Error. And Help To Redirect and Integrate  to openmeetings. Thank you In Advance.

Comment: Have you imported the required libraries in your project?

Comment: which Library required ???

Comment: @Rajan If it says `com.atlassian cannot be resolved` the you need to include the library. Add the library to the build path or deployment assembly if you are deploying the app to a app server.

Comment: will you please explain which library i should add?

Answer (score -1):

Visit **[Atlassian Developers](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/How+to+fix+broken+Extractors)** for help

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever tried the Jira Plugin from the website:
http://openmeetings.apache.org/JiraPlugin.html

or is this actually the plugin code that you are posting here?